# How do I make Django dev server available to the internet?

Tags: python, django, server

I am working on a website with Django and I work with a team of non-developers and I want to show them my progress every week or so but the amount of time and effort I am forced to spend when deploying the contents of my local dev server to the production server is just too much.

As a solution, I installed Django in my home server computer(W 8.1) and did the following:

- Setup port forwading (TCP port 80->80(my home server computer), 8000->8000(the same)
- Disabled windows firewall
- started django dev server with

  python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 and the same with port 8000 but not at the same time.

This allows me to access the site from a different computer in the network but whenever I try to access it through its public IP address, I get the following error message in the Django console:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 595, in process_request_thread
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.1.1', 5027)
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 129, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 116, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 595, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 129, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 116, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I looked up the error but all I got is that this error happens when the server and the client can't agree on which way to communicate. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Making the Django Development server accessible on the Internet is a bad idea.

Comment: @SaeX what does fabric have to do with this?

Comment: @SaeX I understand that it's a bad idea and I only intend to the firewall for a limited time for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @doniyor: wrong package, removed.

Comment: I think you may need to set the IP address argument of the runserver command to the Public IP of your network.  Let me know the results.

Comment: This doesn't fix the error you're getting, but have you considered setting up a project on [cloud9](https://c9.io/)?  It's in browser, so non-developers can access it easily.  They'd still have to type the runserver command in terminal, but it's pretty basic.

Comment: @KevinCherepski It tells me I can't assign that IP.

Comment: @ekrah cloud9 seems like a dirty solution but looks like it may work. But I am hoping for a more of a straight way to access the site

Comment: did the outside person try a different browser? looks a bit strange, it is already in finish_request when the connection breaks away. Is it IE maybe? :D Another idea for you: forward 80 -> 8000 (so outside person does not need port, and server process does not need admin rights).

Comment: You should probably good your deployment process rather than futzing around with the dev server. Using git and fabric I can push new code and restart the server process in just a few seconds. Or use a free heroku  account and you just need git.